# Performing git-fetch with a different user

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

Thanks in advance, and sorry if I am using inexact terminology when it comes to git. I'm trying my best.

How do I perform a git-fetch with a different user than the one I am logged in on? I am using a mac, and I have tried doing this both from the command line and using SourceTree, but failed. Currently I need to go through the following arduous procedure whenever I want to do something git related on the repository I am accessing:

- **Only once:** Create a different user on my system (on the mac I am using) with the exact username that the repository (or the server it is on) is expecting.
- Log into said user on my local system.
- Recursively chown the directory of the local git cloned directory to this user.
- Perform the git fetch.
- Log back to my normal user.
- Recursively chown back to my normal user.

With some scripts this isn't too painful, but these are very big directories I am dealing with, so chowning them takes a while, and I would like to avoid the hassle. I have been doing this for six months now. I am using both the command line and SourceTree, and I have not found a way to get around this with either (SourceTree appears to support using a different username for a repository, but it's not working for me).

Edit: I may not modify the permissions of the files.

Comment: Add yourself and the other user to a group and make the repo group-writable and owned by that group.

Comment: Then you can `sudo -u thatuser git fetch`

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately, I cannot do that - the repository tracks file permissions, and the group permissions do not allow that.

Comment: What leads you to conclude the repository tracks file permissions?

Comment: Ah. Do you perhaps not know about `umask`?  It may be set to mask out the group-writable bit.

Comment: I think it tracks permissions because permissions changes have been committed by mistake once.

Comment: I have read about umask, but either I am not getting it, or it solves a different problem. From what I have gathered, changing it would change the default permissions of newly created files, but would not do anything for me with existing files. Am I mistaken? (Thanks, by the way.)

Comment: Since you can use the other user's ssh credentials yourself this is moot, in case it's useful later: checkout preserves the recorded executable bit, but the rest are set according to umask.  For the repository itself (which is all you need to fetch), the initial setup is just `git init --shared=group` but you can achieve the effect retroactively by chmodding g+rws `.git` and all subdirectories, g+rw all the files there, then g-w all the files under `.git/objects/??`

Answer (score 1):

The unexpected answer to my question is this - inserting "username@" (with the actual username) between the "ssh://" address/protocol-prefix and the address itself via "git config -e", and not through SourceTree's UI, did the trick. Weird.

Comment: Why is that weird? That's the universal solution to this problem: that's part of the URL standard (https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt). Every tool I know that manipulates URL follows this.